Cant access wp-admin after plugin wp-smtp
After installing wp-smtp I can't access the wp-admin.
What I've tried:

renaming the plugins folder to plugins.hold
change the value from active_plugins in the database

Both of these options didn't work.
So I enabled the debugging in the wp-config.php and this is the error I get:

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property
PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer::$Timelimit is deprecated in
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-content/plugins/wp-smtp/wp-smtp.php on
line 198
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
PHPMailer\PHPMailer\fsockopen() in
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/PHPMailer/SMTP.php:423 Stack
trace: #0
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/PHPMailer/SMTP.php(356):
PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP->getSMTPConnection('...', 587, 15, Array) #1
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php(2228):
PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP->connect('...', 587, 15, Array) #2
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-content/plugins/wp-smtp/wp-smtp.php(213):
PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpConnect() #3
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-content/plugins/wp-smtp/wp-smtp.php(55):
WP_SMTP->check_credentials() #4
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-content/plugins/wp-smtp/wp-smtp.php(291):
WP_SMTP->__construct() #5
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-settings.php(517): include_once('...')
#6 /data/sites/web/company/www/wp-config.php(110): require_once('...') #7 /data/sites/web/company/www/wp-load.php(50): require_once('...') #8 /data/sites/web/company/www/wp-admin/admin.php(34):
require_once('...') #9
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-admin/index.php(10):
require_once('...') #10 {main} thrown in
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/PHPMailer/SMTP.php on line 423
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Invalid callback
PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP::errorHandler, cannot access protected method
PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP::errorHandler() in
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/functions.php:6078 Stack
trace: #0 /data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/functions.php(6078):
trigger_error('...', 1024) #1
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/functions.php(6022):
wp_trigger_error('', '...') #2
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/query.php(882):
_doing_it_wrong('...', '...', '...') #3 /data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/robots-template.php(93):
is_embed() #4
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324):
wp_robots_noindex_embeds(Array) #5
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(205):
WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array) #6
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/robots-template.php(32):
apply_filters('...', Array) #7
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/functions.php(3863):
wp_robots() #8
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/functions.php(3785):
_default_wp_die_handler('...', '...', Array) #9 /data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(241):
wp_die(Object(WP_Error), '', Array) #10
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(156):
WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_default_error_template(Array,
Object(WP_Error)) #11
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(60):
WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_error_template(Array,
Object(WP_Error)) #12 [internal function]:
WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle() #13 {main} thrown in
/data/sites/web/company/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6078


Just delete the plugin ?

A deprecation warning isn't an error. It's just  a notification that a feature will cease to work in some future version of PHP. The fatal errors look like some kind of scoping problem.

If you have a problem with a plugin, contact the plugin maintainer in the first instance for support. We can potentially advise how to amend the code if you [edit] your question to provide a [mre] of the issue, but whether it's a good idea to edit a plugin's code is a separate issue - that could invalidate a support agreement (if you have one), and/or make it incompatible with future updates to the plugin, and/or cause other unanticipated consquences which, since you didn't write the code, you may not be able to predict.

@Snuffy I can't access the wp-admin, never used wordpress before, but when i check the  folder wp-content/plugins i don't see the plugin

The fatal eror is related to your php configuration.  My guess is your hosting disable this function but still confirm with them. Deprecated is just notice which have nothing to do with your errors.

@Snuffy what do you think has been disabled, and where in the configuration? There's nothing in those error messages which suggests anything like that, as far as I can see

@ADyson "Call to undefined function PHPMailer\PHPMailer\fsockopen()" - is a core PHP function, and its not available in the PHP environment.  Without fsockopen(), plugins that depend on it, like wp-smtp, will not function correctly and will throw errors. Correct me if im wrong.

@Snuffy well, fsockopen() isn't, and never has been, part of the PHPMailer namespace. So using that function call with the namespace prepended seems to be the issue, wouldn't you say? Demos: https://3v4l.org/n5C1Y and https://3v4l.org/Y3Vk3
